# Прошу помощи с условием задачи

Tags: java

Не до конца понимаю как решать задачу. Есть подозрение что здесь нужен интерфейс Queue. В правильном ли я направлении думаю?

> Реализовать класс, моделирующий работу n-местной автостоянки. Машина подъезжает к определенному месту и едет вправо, пока не встретится свободное место. Класс должен поддерживать методы, обслуживающие приезд и отъезд машины. Определить метод, который выводит в консоль текущее состояние стоянки.

Comment: Достаточно массива.

Comment: @avp здесь хотят просто чтоб я добавлял в коллекцию или массив элемент,удалял элемент и выводил на экран?

Comment: Мне кажется, что да. Просто массив из N элементов. 0 -- место свободно (сначала все свободны), 1 -- занято. Вот и все.

Comment: массив из boolean, удобнее использовать

Comment: PriorityQueue подойдет вполне, не зачем использовать массивы (изобретать велосипед)

Answer (score -1):

это решение правильное?

```
public class Task03 {
private static Car[] list = new Car[5];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Task03 q = new Task03();

    add(q.new Car());
    add(q.new Car());
    add(q.new Car());
    add(q.new Car());
    add(q.new Car());
    add(q.new Car());

    print();
    remove(1);
    print();

}

public static void add(Car car) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i] == null) {
            list[i] = car;
            return;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Мест нет!");
}

public static void remove(int c) {
    try {
        if ((list[c] != null)) {
            list[c] = null;
        } else
            System.out.println("место свободно!");
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("такого номера парковки нет!");
    }
}

public static void print() {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i]==null) {
            System.out.println("Место свободно");
        } else
            System.out.println("Место занято");
    }
}

class Car {

}
```

}

Comment: я бы не зачёл это решение. Тут квадратичная сложность но существует линейное решение (или через кучу хотя бы n log n).

Comment: @pavel поясните пожалуйста ваш комментарий,
что такое квадратичная сложность и n log n?

Comment: @pavel помогите пожалуйста

Comment: ну если в двух словах - то сложность - это Big-O нотация. Использование встроенной приоритетной очереди как вам советовали в комментариях будет быстрее. Или же использовать более эффективные алгоритмы.